# Filter columns in large dataset with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a dataset which is 1,000,000 rows by about 390,000 columns.  The fields are all binary, either 0 or 1.  The data is very sparse.

I've been using Spark to process this data.  My current task is to filter the data--I only want data in 1000 columns that have been preselected.  This is the current code that I'm using to achieve this task:

```
val result = bigdata.map(_.zipWithIndex.filter{case (value, index) => selectedColumns.contains(index)})
```

`bigdata` is just an `RDD[Array[Int]]`

However, this code takes quite a while to run.  I'm sure there's a more efficient way to filter my dataset that doesn't involve going in and filtering every single row separately.  Would loading my data into a DataFrame, and maniuplating it through the DataFrame API make things faster/easier?  Should I be looking into column-store based databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with making your filter a little bit more efficient. Please note that:

- your `RDD` contains `Array[Int]`. It means you can access nth element of each row in *O(1)* time
- #selectedColumns << #columns

Considering these two facts it should be obvious that it doesn't make sense to iterate over all elements for each row not to mention `contains` calls. Instead you can simply `map` over `selectedColumns`

```
// Optional if selectedColumns are not ordered
val orderedSelectedColumns = selectedColumns.toList.sorted.toArray
rdd.map(row => selectedColumns.map(row))
```

Comparing time complexity:

1. `zipWithIndex` + `filter` (assuming best case scenario when `contains` is *O(1)) - O(#rows * # columns)*
2. `map` - *O(#rows * #selectedColumns)*

Comment: I had to to use `selectedColumns.map(row)).deep` so that when I saved my result as a text file the actual data was saved (and not the memory location)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to speed up execution is to parallelize it with partitionBy:

```
bigdata.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions)).foreachPartition(...)
```

foreachPartition receives a Iterator over which you can map and filter.

numPartitions is a val which you can set with the amount of desired parallel partitions.

Comment: So you're saying that simply repartitioning to a greater number of partitions will speed up my filtering of the data?

Comment: yes, if the following criteria is met: a) your data source is splittable (HDFS chunkable for instance) and b) you specify a generous amount of executors - a figure that should reflect the amount of nodes in your cluster and reflect your partitions